# Confused about Irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to determine whether $1+2\sqrt{-2}$ is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, and whether it is prime.

First, recall the definition of a prime element and the definition of an irreducible element in a commutative ring with identity:

> **Definition**. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $p \in R$, $p \neq 0$, and $p \notin U(R)$. Then,
>
> - $p$ is **prime** if $p|xy$ implies that $p|x$ or $p|y$.
> - $p$ is **irreducible** if $p = xy$ implies $x \in U(R)$ (the set of units of $R$) and $y \in U(R)$

In our typed up lecture notes for the course, we have the example of $1 + \sqrt{-3}$ in $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ worked out:

> "Let $z = 1 + \sqrt{-3}$. Then, $Norm(z) = 4$, and we have $4 = 2 \cdot 2 = (1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$.
>
> "We check that $z$ is irreducible. Indeed, for any $w = x+y\sqrt{-3} \in R$ we have $Norm (w) = x^{2}+3y^{2}$. It is straightforward to check that there are no elements $w$ with $Norm(w) = 2$. Hence, for any factorization $z = vw$ we have either $Norm(v) = 1$ or $Norm(w) = 1$; i.e., one of the factors $v$ or $w$ is a unit of $R$. So, it **is** irreducible.
>
> "We check that $z$ is not prime. Indeed, $Norm(w) = x^{2}+3y^{2}$ implies that $U(R) = \{ -1, 1\}$. The element $z$ divides the product $2 \cdot 2$. The number $2$ is irreducible for the same reason as $z$, and hence all divisors of $2$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$. Thus, $z$ does not divide $2$, and so it is **not** prime.

I have a couple of issues with this, though: First off, **how do I check that there are no elements with norm $2$?** When I read the notes, I tried to work this out myself, and did the following, but **I'm not sure it's correct**:

> Suppose there were some $w$ such that $Norm(w) = x^{2}+3y^{2} = 2$. Then, $x^{2} = 2 - 3y^{2}$, which would imply that $x = \pm \sqrt{2-3y^{2}}$. Need $2-3y^{2} \geq 0$, or $2 \geq 3y^{2}$, which implies that $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \geq y^{2}$, so let $y^{2} = 0$, and we must have $y = 0$. But then $x^{2}=2$, or $x = \sqrt{2}$, but it can't because $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$

**If this is not how you're supposed to do it, could somebody please show me how it should be done?**

Second, how exactly are they showing that $2$ is not reducible?

Enough details behind the rationale are not present in the notes, so I'm scratching my head trying to figure it out so that I can use it to base my attempt for $1+2\sqrt{-2}$ in $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ on it.

For $z = 1+2\sqrt{-2}$, $Norm(z)=9$. Now, if I were to proceed the same way as in the example, then, I'd have that $9 = 3 \cdot 3 = (1 + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{-2})(1 - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{-2})$? So, then for any $w = x + y\sqrt{-2} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, we have $Norm(w) = x^{2}+2y^{2}$, and I'd need to figure out whether there existed any elements $w$ with $Norm(w) = 9$: Following the same rationale as before, then $y^{2} \leq 4$, so $y = 2$, $y = 1$, $y = 0$ If $y = 2$, then we get $z$, which, I suppose we don't want, because that wasn't sufficient in the example from the lecture notes I gave above. If $y = 1$, then, $x^{2} = 7$, which we can't have since $x$ would then not be in $\mathbb{Z}$. **So then, we'd have the same case as before?**  If $y=0$, then $x^{2} = 9$, so $x = 3$, so **is it reducible**?

**Then, in the example I gave above, how does $Norm(w) = x^{2}+3y^{2}$ imply that $U(R) = \{ -1, 1\}$**?

I'm very confused about both the example and the problem I'm working on here, and **could use help in figuring out what the correct way to do these kinds of problems is.**

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: You meant $p = xy$ implies $x$ or $y$ is a unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the norm of $a + b \sqrt{-2}$ is $a^2 + 2 b^2,$ which is a positive ordinary integer. The norm is also multiplicative, which means that an element with a norm that is prime is irreducible. In this ring, if the norm is composite, then the element is reducible. Your norm is $1 + 2 \cdot 4 = 9,$ so look for your element as the product of two elements of norm $3.$ Note that elements of norm $3$ can only be the four choices $\pm 1 \pm \sqrt {-2}$

Comment: but I would need to prove that an element with a prime norm is irreducible, don't I? Or is that just "obvious"? Then, for the four choices you give me, I have to show that no combination of those multiplies together to give me $1 + 2\sqrt{-2}$?

Comment: @ALannister please calculate the products of the four choices, one of them times itself or another. Your original element does reduce. The "obvious" part is that an element of norm $1$ is, in fact, a unit.

Comment: $(-1+\sqrt{-2})(1-\sqrt{-2}) = 1+2\sqrt{-2}$, right? Then, $1+2\sqrt{-2}$ is not prime because it does not divide either factor?

Comment: it's the prime part I'm still confused about now...

Comment: oooh wait a minute...$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is an integral domain, isn't it? And in an integral domain, prime $\implies$ irreducible, so not irreducible $\implies$ not prime. Yeah?